# How to remove left and bottom text?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I would like to remove the text from the chart axis? Is it possible? How? Thanks

MPAndroidChart lib
[[image: chart image]]

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: What are you using to make the Gui or something. Need more details. See this on how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 chart.xAxis.setDrawLabels(false)
 chart.axisRight.setDrawLabels(false)
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "removing"? Removing from the picture? If yes, then use photo editors like Photoshop. Is it code and you want to remove these labels? then read the code carefully (or if this chart is created with some libraries, read the docs). Sorry for *inaccurate* answer, because question is not very *clear* to me. I hope I helped you.

Comment: Yes,  This was about MPAndroidChart lib. Sorry, it is my first question